# I Updated build.gradel in android folder but when i comple it still show that i'm using old kotli

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

Im working on my project, when i want to build the app bundle, it says like this

```
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20
```

It shows that i'm using kotlin gradle plugin 1.4.20, but I already updated the `Android/build.gradle`
I've changed `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'`, but on compiler still says like this, i tried many times with flutter clean, flutter pub get but always get the same, please help me

I've changed `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'`, but on compiler still says like this, i tried many times with flutter clean, flutter pub get but always get the same, please help me

Comment: Did yu have this line     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" in android/app/build.gradle ? AND this line        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" in android/build.gradle ?

Answer (score 1):

In the Flutter app, Please check below code

In the 'android/build.gradle' file You need to add below code,

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
}
```

In the 'app/build.gradle' file,You need to add below code,

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.21'
}
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties file,

```
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip`
```

My Android studio version,

```
 Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1
```